# What to do with an IOException in WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()

Tags: android, android-webview, httprequest, ioexception

I am trying to intercept requests from a WebView so that I can inject extra headers. I am applying a WebViewClient to the WebView and overriding `shouldInterceptRequest()`.

In `shouldInterceptRequest()` I open the connection, add the headers, and then return the opened stream in a WebResourceResponse.

It is not clear to me how an IOException should be handled if the initial opening of the connection fails.

```java
final Map<String, String> extraHeaders = getExtraHeaders(intent);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();

        try {
            URL           url = new URL(uri.toString());
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> h : extraHeaders.entrySet()) {
                con.addRequestProperty(h.getKey(), h.getValue());
            }
            final String contentType = con.getContentType().split(";")[0];
            final String encoding    = con.getContentEncoding();
            return new WebResourceResponse(contentType, encoding, con.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // what should we do now?
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
    }
});
```

I can't leave it uncaught, as it's a checked exception and is not part of the `shouldInterceptRequest()` signature.

I can't wrap it in an unchecked exception, as that then goes uncaught by the WebView and kills the app.

If I catch and ignore the exception, and default to the `super` method (which just returns `null`), then the WebView will continue with its default behaviour and attempt to send the request (without my extra headers). This is not desirable, as the WebView's own connection attempt may actually succeed, and the missing headers will cause more problems further down the line.

There seems to be no way to indicate that the intercept has failed and the request should be aborted.

What's the best thing to do here?

---

I have tried to return a mock failure response, but this is not treated as an error. The WebView shows a page with the content of the response (the error message from the exception) and the WebViewClient's `onReceivedError()` or `onReceivedHttpError()` callbacks are not called.

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(e.getMessage().getBytes());
    return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", 500, "Intercept failed",
                                   Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                                   is);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to instantiate a new [WebResourceError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceError.html) and then call [WebViewClient.onReceivedError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError%29). Never tried such a thing, but this is how it would look like:

```
} catch (final IOException e) {
    WebResourceError wre = new WebResourceError(){
        @Override
        public CharSequence getDescription (){
            return e.toString(); 
        }

        @Override
        public int getErrorCode (){
            return WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT;
        }
    };

    onReceivedError(view, request, wre);

    return true;
}
```

There's also a [deprecated version of `onReceivedError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you could use if you don't want or can't instantiate a `WebResourceError`.

Answer (score -1):

Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations.

IOException()
Constructs an IOException with null as its error detail message.

IOException(String message)
Constructs an IOException with the specified detail message.

IOException(String message, Throwable cause)
Constructs an IOException with the specified detail message and cause.

IOException(Throwable cause)
Constructs an IOException with the specified cause and a detail message of (cause==null ? null : cause.toString()) (which ty
pically contains the class and detail message of cause).

you have examples on IOException

here :

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/ioexception/java-io-ioexception-how-to-solve-ioexception/

Comment: This does not answer the question. I know what an IOException is.